# Expand and overlap image over a grid of other images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been fighting with jQuery all night and getting quite frustrated here, so forgive me if the answer was staring me in the face.

I have a 5x3 grid of 15 images contained within a `<div>`, and when I click on one of them, I want it to expand to three times its original size of 150x105 and overlap the rest. I've got the expanding down, but the overlapping isn't quite working.

My current HTML:

```
    <div id="image-grid">
        <img src="images/after-pictures/1.jpg" class="igc1" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/2.jpg" class="igc2" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/3.jpg" class="igc3" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/4.jpg" class="igc4" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/5.jpg" class="igc5" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/6.jpg" class="igc1" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/7.jpg" class="igc2" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/8.jpg" class="igc3" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/9.jpg" class="igc4" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/10.jpg" class="igc5" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/11.jpg" class="igc1" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/12.jpg" class="igc2" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/13.jpg" class="igc3" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/14.jpg" class="igc4" />
        <img src="images/after-pictures/15.jpg" class="igc5" />
    </div>
```

The `igc*` class denotes the column the image is in.

CSS:

```
#image-grid {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 745px;
    padding: 5px 2px 2px 5px;
}

#image-grid img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 105px;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#image-grid img').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '450px',
        height: '315px',
        zIndex: '10'
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: someting like this effect here? http://jsbin.com/evifa3

Comment: Something like that, yes. Just imagine, say, a 3x3 grid of images. When I hover or click on one, I want it to expand and fill the 3x3 grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhat like this...

```
$('#image-grid img').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '450px',
        height: '315px'
    }, 200)
    .css({
        'z-index': function (i, z) {
            return z + 10;
        }, position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    })
    .siblings().css({
        'z-index': function (i, z) {
            return z - 10;
        }, position: 'static',
        width: '150px',
        height: '105px',
        left: 'auto',
        top: 'auto'
    });
});​
```

let me know what's the effect..

Comment: That code does nothing in Firefox and Chrome, I'm afraid. Though you do know that the `img` tag has no siblings, right?

Comment: I don't know what's not working for you, but here's a demo... http://jsfiddle.net/mMuYF/2/ and given by your html structure, img tags has lots of img tags as it's siblings...

Comment: Oh, I was confusing siblings with children. Oops.

Comment: OK, it appears to be working now...not sure what was wrong before. It'll need some tweaking, but I'm pretty sure I can do that on my own. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're trying to apply a z-index to elements which have not been given the position absolute property also?

Comment: you don't really have to go absolute... relative is just fine... and besides, absolute positioning gives lots of trouble if your purpose was just really the z-index...

Comment: The images not being affected by jQuery don't have a set positioning. I tried adding a z-index to them; didn't help, so I deleted it, and it still didn't work. I don't want to do absolute, because then I'd have to go through and set pixel values for each image, and that sort of defeats my goal of simplicity.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I should've been broader in my statement - you may need to just apply positioning in general, so the t/r/b/l values take hold. So as Reigel mentions, apply position:relative to the images beforehand.
Or find a fix like you did above!! :P